# How to load cookies if after logging it changes the domain (Python + Chromedriver)

Tags: python, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

Summary:
when adding cookies it gives an error

> <class 'selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException'>
> Message: invalid cookie domain: Cookie 'domain' mismatch

Description:
I try to add cookies to Chromedriver using python code:

```
for i in cookie:
try:
    browser.add_cookie(i)
    print(browser.get_cookies())
    browser.refresh()
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e), e, sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno)
```

there are 2 list items in the cookie file:

```
[{'domain': '.example.net', 'expiry': 111, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'reme', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': '1111'},
{'domain': 'member.example.net', 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'reme22', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': '2222'}]
```

Since after entering the login and password, the domain changes to **member.example.net**, an error occurs when adding cookies at the 2nd step of the cycle

Is it possible to somehow bypass the error, and load the cookies of the logged in user after site openings then do driver.refresh? Then it was not necessary to enter a login and password

Comment: maybe you should set it later. OR maybe you should run brower with `profile` which would have all cookies.

Comment: it's good idea about run brower with profile. need to search info how to do that

Comment: when you create `driver` then you ca set profile as `Options` - but details may depends on browse. Different options may need `Chrome`/`Edge` and different `Firefox`. I don't remeber details